# How do I get the edges that connect two nodes in a Pygraphviz undirected (and not strict) graph (Agraph) or in NetorkX graph

Tags: networkx, pygraphviz

Assume that I have a graph with multiple edges connecting the same nodes

```
graph foo {
        1 -- 2;
        1 -- 2 [key=tt];
        1 -- 2 [color=blue];
}
```

How do I get all the edges between nodes 1 and 2?
How do I change/add individual attributes for these nodes?

I have looked at networkx and also there is no way to get the list of edges between two nodes.

Sorry if I missed something here I am learning these modules.

PS: I still can't figure out why you can't use directed=False to create an undirected Agraph. There are workarounds here on this site but nobody is explaining why even if you set this graph attribute when you create the graph it doesn't work

Update: nx.nx_agraph.write_dot(G,"test.dot") will print a directed graph although the original G was a undirected graph

Update2: pygraphviz v1.3.1, Python 3.4 x86, Win10 x64 (the only version I could find a wheel for Pygraphviz) Trying to install from sources/github failed with

graphviz_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyIOBase_Type
    build\lib.win32-3.7\pygraphviz_graphviz.cp37-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120